# Understanding QGIS API documentation to write Python code using QgsVectorLayer?

Tags: pyqgis

I am not sure how to use the API documentation to code in Python.
For example, I want to determine whether a layer is a point, line or polygon layer and found the following in the API documentation:

[image]

I have selected the lakes shapefile from the QGIS alaska dataset. In the QGis Python console, I have typed:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *
canvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()
cLayer = canvas.currentLayer()
type(cLayer)
```

The returned value is: `<class 'qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer'>`.

How do I use the above information in the API documentation to (1) determine the type of the selected layer and (2) return the value of the listed enumerate types (e.g. polygon)?  Whilst I am sure someone can tell me the answer, I would really like to know how to work out the answer using the API documentation and any other available documentation.

Answer (score 8):

`QgsLayerItem` isn't what you want for this. That is the item that is shown in the QGIS browser widget.

What you want to do is look up `QgsVectorLayer` which lands you here http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html that is all the methods on the vector layer, however QgsVectorLayer is inherited from QgsMapLayer.  You can see this by expanding the ***Inheritance diagram for QgsVectorLayer:*** section.  Clicking on QgsMapLayer takes you too http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html there you can see `QgsMapLayer::LayerType`

You can also see that `QgsMapLayer` has a type method `QgsMapLayer::type()` (http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html#a209afd81e5d57a7d909acab01ed608e0) you can see this returns `QgsMapLayer::LayerType`.  Because `QgsVectorLayer` and `QgsRasterLayer` inherit from `QgsMapLayer` they both have the `type()` method.

So now we can do:

```
layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer
```

to check if it's a vector layer.

If you click on the return type it will also take you to the docs for that type

[image]