# Understanding QgsLayoutItemLegend of PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, python-3, pyqgis-3

As I get more into QGIS scripting, I refer to the documentation often and usually without success. I have trouble deciphering how to interpret the classes, etc.

[I found this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279734/understanding-qgis-api-documentation) which is really the same question and it helps a bit but I am still confused.

Let's take the QgsLayoutItemLegend class for example from the documentation:

Now, I think I understand that in order to create a legend item and add it to my Print Layout, I would do something like this...

```
QgsLayoutItemLegend.create(legend)
```

In the QGIS python editor I am prompted to include arguments for the function, which is helpful. It looks like this:
[image]

I look in the [documentation for the QgsLayoutItemLegend.create()](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsLayoutItemLegend.html?highlight=layoutitemlegend#qgis.core.QgsLayoutItemLegend.create) method and see this below, which I cannot make sense of:
[image]

I see nothing about the arguments this method takes in the documentation.

How do I create a Legend using QgsLayoutItemLegend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create it directly, using the layout as the only argument:

```
legend=QgsLayoutItemLegend(layout)
```

Then you must add the newly created item to the layout (this isn't done automatically):

```
layout.addItem(legend)
```